# Classification shown as "Classifi cation"

Tags: latex

The following latex code:

```
\subsection{Classification Performance}
```

is shown something like

> 5.3.3 Classifi cation Performance

There seems to be some gap beteen "Classifi" and "cation". Is it a problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Where do you see this? DVI, PDF, other output file?

Comment: Not in dvi or ps, but in pdf. I complie with latex dvips and ps2pdf. And outside \subsection{...} it shows fine.

Comment: Zoom on it or print it on paper. you will see there is no problem. issue is related to low resulation fonts (not hinted) and rasterization.

Comment: Which font you are using? are you using fontspec or titlesec pacckages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does:

```
% test.tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

  \subsection{Classification Performance}

\end{document}
```

produce something different than:

[image]

When generating a PDF of it like this:

```
latex test.tex && dvipdf test.dvi
```

on your system?

Comment: no, it doesn't. Thanks! Why dvipdf makes a difference than dvips and ps2pdf?

Comment: @Tim, sorry, I have no idea why it doesn't. When executing `latex test.tex && dvips test.dvi && ps2pdf test.ps`, it gives me the exact same thing (no gap between "Classifi" and "cation"). The PS file also looks the same as the PDF.